# Automatic vertical spacing swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am working on an app in swift and I am facing difficulties with automatic vertical spacing between elements :

I have a tableview which height may vary from one page to another so I added this lines to my code

```
var frame = tableView.frame
frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
tableView.frame = frame
```

but when one tableview have several entries, the vertical spacing bewteen the tableview and the button below does not change and the content in the tableview goes on the button

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. use bound property instead of frame. 2. did u used auto layout?

Comment: 1. I tried with bound property and the problem remains 2. Yes I'm using auto layout

Comment: okay can u upload image?